# Mongodb setting a value in an array without .$

Tags: mongodb

I have the query

```
choices.update({"subchoices.id":'fh3284'},
               {$set : { "subchoices.$.name" : "le_new_choice"}}
               );
```

the document:

```
{ subchoices : [ { "id" : "fh3284", name : "choice1" },
                 { "id" : "fh3286", name : "choice2" } 
               ], ... }
```

Is it possible to rewrite this without using the `.$.` operator for the (on its own not the one in the `$set`,`$query`, etc)? Im using meteor and the client side implementation which doesn't take the `.$.` yet.

Comment: is the question whether you can update an element of an array without using positional operator?  You can if you know the position.

Comment: Is this the only way?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that impossible to do such update withou .$. 
I've spent a lot of time to try to sovle it, but couldn't.